# I can not receive files from my phone by bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I can not send files by bluetooth from my cell phone to the computer, they always give an error and do not send (I do not get it on the computer that is trying to get a file to accept it or deny it)

The funny thing is that from the computer files can be sent correctly to that mobile by bluetooth.

I have looked at all the possible configuration options, I have tried the blueman also and nothing at all, I do not know what to do ...

Comment: I'm having the same problem with ftp. But it's opposite. I can send files by ftp from my cell phone to the computer. However, I can't send from the computer files to that mobile. I think it's any limitation of pantheon-files. I tried with nautilus and it works the both.

Comment: I have the same problem. Asked a hundred times here and on their irc but didn't get an answer that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, what worked for me is

right click blueman icon> Local services > check 'accept files from trusted devices' under 'transfer settings'.

hope this helps.

try this link to troubleshoot any bluetooth problems

http://support.system76.com/articles/bluetooth/